# how to only make logout button appear with no CSS from a separate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

I want to show ONLY the `<Logout/>` button from the `<Title/>` component on the same row of the title but only when the user has made it to `<Home/>` component.

In other words, I don't want the CSS from `<Title/>` to be incorporated inside the `<Home/>` component because then it'll just be repeating itself.

I want it to show on the same row as the title only when they've logged in successfully and they're in `<Home/>`

How would I go about making this happen?

(If you need more information please let me know or if it's unclear)

[image: Repeating Title]

Here's `Title.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classes from './Title.css';
import LogoutButton from '../../containers/LogoutButton/LogoutButton';

class Title extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            showLogoutButton: this.props.authenticated
        };
    }

    render() {
        const { showLogoutButton } = this.state;
          return(
            <div className="row" style={{"display": "flex"}}>
                {showLogoutButton && <LogoutButton/>}
                <h1 className={classes.Title}>Pick Ups</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Title;
```

Here's `Home.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './Home.css';
import Title from '../../components/Title/Title';

class Home extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Title authenticated= {true}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Here's `LogoutButton.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import fire from '../../config/Fire';
import classes from './LogoutButton.css';

class LogoutButton extends Component {
    logout = () => {
        fire.auth().signOut();
    };

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <button className={classes.LogoutButton} onClick={this.logout.bind(this)}>Logout</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LogoutButton;
```

Comment: Show the `LogoutButton` code? Also right now they are in different rows?

Comment: @ArupRakshit just posted `<LogoutButton/>` code.  My title is being repeated when I place `<Title/>` in the `<Home/>` component but I only want to show the logout button from there, not the actual title along with its CSS.

Comment: can you add a screenshot , so that I can see what you meant by repeating..?

Comment: @ArupRakshit just added a screenshot to my original post.  All I want is the logout button, not the actual title itself.

Comment: @sp then only render the button, not the <Title> inside the Home? Instead of `<Title authenticated= {true}/>`, do render just `<LogoutButton />`

Comment: @ArupRakshit yes that works, but I want it on the same line at the Title

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179935/discussion-between-arup-rakshit-and-sp92).